# Incorrect decrement of the reference count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have the following problem: In one flow of the execution I use alloc, and on the other flow, alloc is not needed.
At the end of the if statement, in any case, I release the object.
When I do 'build and Analize' I get an error: 'Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object is not owned by the caller'.

How to solve that?

```
UIImage *image; 

int RandomIndex = arc4random() % 10;

if (RandomIndex<5) 
{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"dd"];
}
else 
{
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"];
}


UIImageView *imageLabel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[image release];
[imageLabel release];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You should `retain` the image in the second condition:**

```
image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"] retain];
```

This way, both possible exits out of the condition will have an object with a reference count of one, from your point of view.

Otherwise, you are trying to `release` an already `autorelease`d object!

Answer (score 8):

You can either do what others have suggested, or:

```
if (RandomIndex<5) 
{
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"dd"];
}
else 
{
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"];
}

UIImageView *imageLabel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
...
[imageLabel release];
```

This way, in both cases you are getting an autoreleased object `image`, which you do not then need to release yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"];
```

Do:

```
image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"] retain];
```

Comment: Or the other way, set the alloc'd one to autorelease.

Answer (score 2):

`imageNamed` returns an **autoreleased** object. 
You can only release an object that you have ownership of.

This will work:

```
if (RandomIndex<5) 
{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"dd"] autorelease];
}
else 
{
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dd"];
}


UIImageView *imageLabel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageLabel release];
```